# How does quicksort in Haskell work?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

On the [Haskell website](http://www.haskell.org), there's this example [quicksort implementation](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Introduction#Quicksort_in_Haskell):

```
quicksort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
quicksort []     = []
quicksort (p:xs) = (quicksort lesser) ++ [p] ++ (quicksort greater)
    where
        lesser  = filter (< p) xs
        greater = filter (>= p) xs
```

There is an explanation on the site, but I have a couple of questions that I didn't see were addressed ...

- where is the actual comparison/swap done on two elements for a re-order? Is this handled by the 'Ord' (ordered) type definition itself. So the type enforces this condition of being ordered?
- the 'greater' filter defines items '>= p' (the pivot), so doesn't this mean we'll end up with an extra pivot [p] in resulting list of the function, due to the '++ [p]' item?

Comment: For the record, `greater` isn't a predicate (a function of type `a -> Bool`); it's just the result of `filter (>= p) xs`, which has type `Ord a => [a]`, i.e., a list of `a`s.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> where is the actual comparison/swap done on two elements for a
>   re-order? Is this handled by the `Ord` (ordered) type definition
>   itself. So the type enforces this condition of being ordered?

### What does `Ord` mean?

`Ord` just means that `a` should be comparable with itself or in stricter terms operations such as `>`, `<`, and `==` should be defined for `a`. You can think of it as a constraint on the method.

### So, where is the ordering done?

And the answer is the last pattern:

```
quicksort (p:xs) = (quicksort lesser) ++ [p] ++ (quicksort greater)
    where
        lesser  = filter (< p) xs
        greater = filter (>= p) xs
```

At run time, the program is going to get an array and the array must meet either of these two patterns:

Pattern 1#: It is empty, in which case the function returns that same empty array and stops.

Pattern 2#: It is not empty or in other words, there is a head element `p` appended to a tailing array `xs`. In such a case, the function is told to put `p` in the middle, put all elements of `xs` that are less than `p` on the left (as defined by `lesser`) of `p` and all elements of `xs` that are greater than or equal to `p` on the right of `p`. Furthermore, the function is finally told to apply itself (i.e., the same function `quicksort`) on `lesser` (which as we defined above, is the array on the left hand side of `p`) and `greater` (which as we defined above, is the array on the right hand side of `p`). As you can see, this will go on till you are left with a zero sized array and pattern 1# terminates the function.

Finally, whenever those recursive calls terminate the function shall return the array:

```
sortedlesser ++ p ++ sortedgreater
```

where `sortedlesser` is the array that resulted from the application of `quicksort` on `lesser` and `sortedgreater` is the array that resulted from the application of `quicksort` on `greater`.

### Wait… are we not duplicating p again and again?

> the 'greater' predicate defines items '>= p' (the pivot), so doesn't
>   this mean we'll end up with an extra pivot [p] in resulting list of
>   the function, due to the '++ [p]' item?

No, this is not how pattern matching works. It is saying all elements in `xs` that are greater than or equal to `p`. By definition `p` itself is out of `xs`. If there are duplicates of `p` in `xs` then they will fall on the right hand side. Note that this choice will preserve the natural ordering of the original array.

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up. I was thinking that the pattern matching was just comparing the values and didn't think it would actually exclude p from the result.

Comment: :) I think it is customary here on SO to delete non-essential comments. You'll notice I deleted mine, you can delete your comments addressed to me now too, I think. :)

Answer (score 33):

1. There is no swap, because this is not the (almost-)in-place version of QS. Instead, new lists are built and then concatenated — comparison is done when `lesser` and `greater` are created, with `<`, `>=` — `Ord` is a typeclass restricting `a` to be orderable — if it wasn't used, you wouldn't be able to use `<` or `>=`.
2. No, because the pivot is not part of `xs` — pattern match splits input list into `p` and `xs`.

Here's crappy ASCII visualisation:

```
                                qs [5, 5, 6, 3, 1]
                                          |
                         qs [3, 1]   ++  [5] ++ qs [5, 6]
                             |            |       |
                  qs [1] ++ [3] ++ qs []  |    qs [] ++ [5] ++ qs [6]
                             |            |       |
                           [1, 3]    ++  [5]  ++ [5, 6]
                             \            |        /
                              \-------------------/
                                        |
                                  [1, 3, 5, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 8):

Note that you can write this even shorter and more performant (as `partition` scans the original list only once) using

```
quicksort [] = []
quicksort (p:xs) = (quicksort lesser) ++ [p] ++ (quicksort greater)
    where (lesser, greater) = partition (< p) xs
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want only one line:

```
qsortOneLine s = case s of{[]->[];(x:xs)->qsortOneLine [y | y<-xs, y<x] ++ x : qsortOneLine [y | y<-xs, y>=x]}
```

If you want more performant code:

```
qsort3 :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
qsort3 x = qsort3' x []
qsort3' [] y     = y
qsort3' [x] y    = x:y
qsort3' (x:xs) y = part xs [] [x] []  
      where
         part [] l e g = qsort3' l (e ++ (qsort3' g y))
         part (z:zs) l e g 
             | z > x     = part zs l e (z:g) 
             | z < x     = part zs (z:l) e g 
             | otherwise = part zs l (z:e) g
```

http://en.literateprograms.org/Quicksort_(Haskell)